# Check Format error response in Travelport Universal API AirCreateReservationReq

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, soap-client, travelport-api

I am using the **Travelport Universal API** in **Trial** mode right now. My goal is to develop a Web Portal for handling B2B requirements of a client. All is well until I came to the second last step, i.e. **Creating reservation** (Booking). I have tried to fill the request object with all the required parameters and data by following the sample Soap request XML attached below:[Sample XML Request](https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/uapi/Content/SampleWeb/SampleFiles/024-03_1G_AirBook_Rq.xml)

Following is the request code that I wrote to include the details as described in the sample xml request.

```
var biPoint3 = new BillingPointOfSaleInfo { OriginApplication =      Crediantels.oritionApplication };

var delevieryInfo = new DeliveryInfo
        {
            Email = new Email { EmailID = "test@travelport.com", Type = "Home" },
            PhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber
            {
                CountryCode = "069",
                AreaCode = "49",
                Number = "261111111",
                Type = PhoneNumberType.Mobile,
                Location = "FRA"
            },
            ShippingAddress = new DeliveryInfoShippingAddress
            {
                City = "Como",
                Country = "IT",
                PostalCode = "22100",
                Street = new[] { "Some Street" }
            },
        };

        var travelerDetails = new BookingTraveler
        {
            Key = "0",
            DOB = new DateTime(1976, 11, 18),
            Gender = "M",
            TravelerType = "ADT",
            BookingTravelerName = new BookingTravelerName
            {
                First = "Frederick",
                Last = "Heinrich",
                Prefix = "Herr"
            },
            Address = new[]
            {
                new typeStructuredAddress
                {
                    AddressName = "Smiths",
                    City = "Frankfurt",
                    Country = "DE",
                    PostalCode = "60311",
                    Street = new[] {"Rossmarkt 6"},
                    State = new State {Value = "Hesse"}
                }
            },
            DeliveryInfo = new[]
            {
                new DeliveryInfo
                {
                    Email = new Email {EmailID = "test@travelport.com", Type = "Home"},
                    PhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber
                    {
                        CountryCode = "069",
                        AreaCode = "49",
                        Number = "261111111",
                        Type = PhoneNumberType.Mobile,
                        Location = "FRA"
                    },
                    ShippingAddress = new DeliveryInfoShippingAddress
                    {
                        City = "Frankfurt",
                        Country = "DE",
                        PostalCode = "60311",
                        Street = new[] {"Rossmarkt 6"}
                    }
                }
            },
            Email = new[] { new Email { Type = "Home", EmailID = "test@travelport.com" } },
            PhoneNumber = new[]
            {
                new PhoneNumber
                {
                    CountryCode = "069",
                    AreaCode = "49",
                    Number = "261111111",
                    Type = PhoneNumberType.Mobile,
                    Location = "FRA"
                }
            }
        };

        var reservationRequest = new AirCreateReservationReq
        {
            BillingPointOfSaleInfo = biPoint3,
            TargetBranch = Crediantels.targetBranch,
            AirPricingSolution = airPriceResponse.AirPriceResult[0].AirPricingSolution[0],
            DeliveryInfo = delevieryInfo,
            BookingTraveler = new[] { travelerDetails },
            FormOfPayment = new[]
            {
                new FormOfPayment
                {
                    Type = "Cash",
                    Key = "jwt2mcK1Qp27I2xfpcCtAw=="
                }
            },
            ActionStatus = new[]
            {
                new ActionStatus
                {
                    Type = ActionStatusType.TTL,
                    TicketDate = "2014-12-07T00:00:00",
                    ProviderCode = "1G",
                    QueueCategory = "01"
                }
            },
            AuthorizedBy = "myself",
            RetainReservation = typeRetainReservation.Both,
            TraceId = "1234"
        };

        if (reservationRequest.AirPricingSolution.AirSegmentRef != null)
        {
            var airSegmentRef = reservationRequest.AirPricingSolution.AirSegmentRef[0].Key;
            reservationRequest.AirPricingSolution.AirSegment = new[] { GetAirSegmentByKey(airPriceResponse, airSegmentRef) };
        }
        reservationRequest.AirPricingSolution.AirSegmentRef = null;
        reservationRequest.AirPricingSolution.AirPricingInfo[0].PassengerType[0].BookingTravelerRef = "0";

        var reservationBinding = new AirCreateReservationBinding
        {
            Url = Crediantels.url,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Crediantels.userName, Crediantels.password)
        };
        //SoapException on the following line
        var airReservationResponse = reservationBinding.service(reservationRequest);
```

But when I send the request, I receive SoapException on the last line mentioned in the code above. The exception is: `Ticketing application failed: CHECK FORMAT`.

Usually the response always contains a clue on what is missing or what is not present in the request as per the expectation of the web service.

I have tried to add all the details in the request even if I don't require some of them, just to match the sample request but still this exception is not going away.

If I intentionally skip something that is mentioned as required in the documentation, I get an intelligible response mentioning the missing item or detail but not in the original case.

I would appreciate any thoughts which may lead me to the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved the issue with some hit and trials. Posting here as an answer to help someone else looking for the same.

The error was given because of the `ActionStatusType.TTL`. It needed to be set to **`ActionStatusType.TAW`**. TAW stands for `TicketAtWill`.

By changing that my error was changed to **`*0 AVAIL/WL Closed*`**. But it was because there were no flights available for booking for the input criteria. Changing the criteria to more extended Departure and Return dates, I got a valid response with reservation details.

```
ActionStatus = new[]
{
    new ActionStatus
    {
        Type = ActionStatusType.TAW, ***
        TicketDate = "2014-12-07T00:00:00",
        ProviderCode = "1G",
        QueueCategory = "01"
    }
 },
```

Comment: can you help me with this exception when trying to reserve a ticket : 
Message From Galileo : Uncaught Service Exception cause:com.cendant.tds.soa.framework.ServiceException: Exception ReturnedERR: AGENT ID - GALILEO
|+With the Dynamic GTID list of:A809C5

Comment: I need to use TTL action status, but I am getting CHECK FORMAT error.